# Testing CodeIgniter Controller functions with different possible scenarios

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I am little wonder about testing the codeIgniter controller functions with different sets of input parameters. 
Is this really possible by writing little piece of code ? I am aware of CodeIgniter inbuilt library "unit_test", but to use this i have to write too many scenarios for testing Login process itself.
I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.2 with MySql as data store and LDAP for user authentication

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is there any way to automate process of unit testing by just supplying input parameter sets and expected result through CVS or XLS file